# Package tried to add reference to System.Runtime which was not found in the GAC

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, package, nuget

ASP.NET 4.5.1 or 4.5.2

Updating Nuget package MicrosoftAspNet.Identity.EntityFramework from version 2.2.1 to version 3.0.0-rc1-final

I get the following error:

Failed to add reference. The package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' tried to add a framework reference to 'System.Runtime' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the package. Please contact the package 
owners for assistance.

Answer (score 29):

I had a similar issue with another package.

I "solved" it adding a manually reference to missed library, updating the package and then removing the reference added manually:

- On your project go to **References** -> **Add Reference...** and then click on **Browse...**
- On my installation (Windows 10), your file is located on: **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll**

Add, update and then remove.

I know, it is not a solution, but it will allow you continue working until get a real solution.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, but adding the MySQL package to my project.

The way that i solved was just very closely to the answer given by Sebastián Guerrero.

So i will be adding a manually reference to that missed library (system.runtime) and than installed the MySQL package and it works perfectly.

**ATTENTION**: I only unnistall the system.runtime package after installing the MySQL.

> References -> Add Reference... and then click on Browse...
>
> On my installation (Windows 10), your file is located on:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when running `Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` on .NET framework 4.5.2

Solved the issue with the following steps:

1. Installed Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime latest version from Nuget.
2. After that, installed latest version of Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent from Nuget.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I opened the project after a while.

The problem was it was originally built with `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0` and I was on `3.3.1`.

The project strangely added two required `Imports` to the `.csproj` file, one for the `2.4.0` compiler,and a duplicate for the `3.3.1` version. I just needed to:

- Right click on the project file
- Unload the project
- Edit the csproj file
- Remove the 2.4.0 references (was also a reference in an Error element)
- Close file
- Right click on project, reload file.
- Rebuild All