# Nuget-package not adding package reference

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to install **MySql.Data** and **MySql.Data.Entity** to my class lib.

Somehow there is no reference added to the project.

Things I've tried:

1. `Update-Package -reinstall` (does not help)
2. `packages.config` contains the correct entries
3. `*.csproj` also has the correct entries
4. Cleared NuGet-Cache

This is the output:

```
Package 'MySql.Data.6.10.6' already exists in folder 
'C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\Repositories\XXXXXXX\packages'
Added package 'MySql.Data.6.10.6' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'MySql.Data 6.10.6' to XXXXXXXX.Persistence
Executing nuget actions took 1,6 sec
```

[image]

Strange thing is that `NuGet` creates that `\docs` in my project which is part of `MySql`

Comment: My only guess is that your project targets .NET 4.5.1 or lower. However you say that the .csproj has the correct entries, so I am assuming there are Reference items in the .csproj file that point to MySql.Data.dll - if that is the case then it is a different problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Nuget-package not adding package reference

I agree with Matt`s comment. You project targets framework should be .NET 4.5.1 or below. Because the package **MySql.Data** **only** contain assembly reference to **.NET framework 4.5.2** for .NET framework:

[image]

However, this package also have the **content** files, which are compatible with .net framework. So when you add this package to the project(target framework 4.5.1 or below), nuget will install this nuget package without any error, **just add the content file (`\docs`) but not add any reference to the project**.

To resolve this issue, you can change the target framework to 4.5.2 and above of this project or you should use the nuget package `MySql.Data` with the version **6.9.11**, which contain assembly reference to **.NET framework 4.0 and 4.5**:

[image]

Note: If you change the target framework to the .net framework 4.5.2 and above, you may get the error "`The package 'MySql.Data' tried to add a framework reference to 'System.ComponentModel' which was not found in the GAC.`", please add a manually reference to missed library:

[Package tried to add reference to System.Runtime which was not found in the GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661210/package-tried-to-add-reference-to-system-runtime-which-was-not-found-in-the-gac/41293475)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem even though I had the correct Framework.
It was solved by [Migrating the Nuget Format to Package References](https://blog.nuget.org/20180409/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

For visual studio latest versions you have to right click on Dependencies > Manage NuGet Packages > click in the settings button with a flower-like shape, then in NuGet Package Manager option choose General, and change Default package management format from packages.config to PackageReference.

[image]

If that does not do the trick, then you will have to add the packages through the CLI tools, looking into the nuget gallery and pasting the comand directly with the desired version, like for example:

`dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design --version 6.0.10`